# ffmpeg fails to copy, creates 2 second video

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I want to copy a portion of a 15 minutes MP4 video, from 11:23 for 46 seconds.

I ran this command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 11:23:00 -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -t 46 output.mp4
```

This generates a 2 second video, that has no audio and shows just 1 frame.

Any idea what could be the problem? Or how could I debug this issue further?

Answer (score 1):

This worked if I removed the milliseconds from the start time:

```
ffmpeg -ss 11:23 -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -t 46 output.mp4
```

I have no logical explanation for why this change made it work though.

Comment: At a guess, perhaps `ffmpeg` was thinking you meant 11 hours and 23 minutes. Milliseconds would likely be `11:23.000` (or perhaps `00:11:23.000`).